# Pagination in bar chart with series

Tags: jasper-reports, bar-chart

I have to create a bar chart which can have a large amount (around 50) of categories (X Axis). I wish to split this report into multiple pages so that I can apply pagination. I have found an answer here:

[How can I generate paginated bar chart in jasper report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339325/how-can-i-generate-paginated-bar-chart-in-jasper-report)

But the above answer discusses a bar chart with single series.
Following is a sample report which I intend to create:

[image: Report]

Assuming we have around 50 dates in X axis, the report will become large. So I have to break this report such that I am showing a configurable amount (say 3) of categories per page. Following is my approach:

1. Create a group of date field
2. Create a variable which counts this group.
3. Create another group with groupExpression $V{variable1} - 1 - ( ($V{variable1} - 1) % 3 )

Following is the jrxml file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="paginationBar3d" language="groovy" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="a9331cff-3045-47b5-8399-17a89e2ac39c">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[select a.year_built, aty.description, count(*) as count
        from aircraft a, aircraft_types aty
        where a.aircraft_type_id = aty.aircraft_type_id
        group by year_built, description order by a.year_built;]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="year_built" class="java.sql.Date">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="description" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="count" class="java.lang.Long"/>
    <variable name="variable1" class="java.lang.Integer" incrementType="Group" incrementGroup="yearGroup" calculation="Count">
        <variableExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.TRUE]]></variableExpression>
    </variable>
    <group name="yearGroup">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{year_built}]]></groupExpression>
    </group>
    <group name="splitter">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$V{variable1} - 1 - ( ($V{variable1} - 1) % 3)]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="802">
                <bar3DChart>
                    <chart>
                        <reportElement uuid="7114e305-2cfb-4757-b034-b0a12dd412d9" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="802"/>
                        <chartTitle/>
                        <chartSubtitle/>
                        <chartLegend/>
                    </chart>
                    <categoryDataset>
                        <dataset resetType="Group" resetGroup="splitter"/>
                        <categorySeries>
                            <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$F{description}]]></seriesExpression>
                            <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{year_built}]]></categoryExpression>
                            <valueExpression><![CDATA[$F{count}]]></valueExpression>
                        </categorySeries>
                    </categoryDataset>
                    <bar3DPlot>
                        <plot/>
                        <itemLabel/>
                        <categoryAxisFormat>
                            <axisFormat/>
                        </categoryAxisFormat>
                        <valueAxisFormat>
                            <axisFormat/>
                        </valueAxisFormat>
                    </bar3DPlot>
                </bar3DChart>
            </band>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
</jasperReport>
```

This generates a single category per page. What should be the correct approach in this scenario?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above report works as intended if I define yearGroup after splitter. I am not sure how ordering of groups matter.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Reports Group, I have done it earlier ,

You can try this Link :-
[Split a chart in to multiple pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15339325/how-can-i-generate-paginated-bar-chart-in-jasper-report/15354409?noredirect=1#comment26265483_15354409)

and just replace

```
               $V{REPORT_COUNT} - 1 - ( ($V{REPORT_COUNT} - 1) % 3 )
```

with

```
               $V{REPORT_COUNT} - 1 - ( ($V{REPORT_COUNT} - 1) % 18 )
```

Comment: Yes but this will limit 18 bars in the chart per page but I have a variable number of series. If I have 4 categories with 5 series making a total of 20 bars, last category will be truncated. I can change 18 to 10 in the above equation but my series is variable.

Comment: You can add variables for series and categories                      $V{REPORT_COUNT} - 1 - ( ($V{REPORT_COUNT} - 1) %   ($V{Number_of_Series} * $V{Number_of_Categories}) )